# ArrayList Iterator fails to iterate

Tags: java, arraylist, data-structures, iterator

My iterator which I've written, doesnt iterate as planned. It should iterate over an ArrayList but it keep looping over the first item: `aylmao`

Goal is to have a working custom iterator which will iterate a generic ArrayList

I'd very much rather ask this in the chat but no one is there atm.

Heres the trouble causing code:

---

```
    @Override
public Iterator<T> iterator() {
    final SimpleList<T> list = this;

    return new Iterator<T>() {

        int index = 0;

        @Override
        public boolean hasNext() {
            return index < list.size() && list.get(index) != null;
        }

        @Override
        public T next() {
            T temp = list.get(index++);
            index++;
            return temp;
        }

        public void remove() {
            throw new UnsupportedOperationException();
        }
    };

}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    SimpleList<String> list = new SimpleList<String>();
    list.append("aylmao");
    list.append("1aylmao");
    list.append("2aylmao");
    list.append("3aylmao");
    list.append("4aylmao");
    list.append("5aylmao");
    list.append("6aylmao");

    while (list.iterator().hasNext()) {

        System.out.println(list.iterator().next());
    }
}
```

Comment: why do you increase index twice?

Comment: one to return the next item and one to move the index one position forward

Comment: you don't need to do that, you want to return what's at the current index, then increase the index. just do return list.get(index++);

Comment: just noticed it myself, thanks for the suggestion, question is answered. you guys rock

Comment: glad we could help, cheers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Calling list.iterator() creates a new iterator every time.

`Iterator<String> iter = list.iterator()` will solve your problem

Just re-use iter.

For example:

```
SimpleList<String> list = new SimpleList<String>();
    list.append("aylmao");
    list.append("1aylmao");
    list.append("2aylmao");
    list.append("3aylmao");
    list.append("4aylmao");
    list.append("5aylmao");
    list.append("6aylmao");
    Iterator<String> iter = list.iterator()
    while (iter.hasNext()) {

        System.out.println(iter.next());
    }
```

Comment: I'll try it and mark your answer once it works, thanks

Comment: See edit by @zython the print needs to use the variable also

Answer (score 1):

Assign the iterator to the variable then add it to while-loop. list.iterator(); creates a new Iterator everytime.

```
Iterator iter = list.iterator();
while(iter.hasNext())
{
   System.out.println(iter.next());
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Use :

```
for (Iterator<String> iterator = list.iterator(); iterator.hasNext();) 
{
   System.out.println(iterator.next());
}
```